# how to define less operator for sruct containing vector of int

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, operators

For the following program I am unable to get increasing order and decreasing order in sync. As you can see in output increasing and decreasing order are not same.

Program :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

struct box{
    vector<int> dim;
    int index;
    box(vector<int> temp, int ind)
    {
        dim = temp;
        index = ind;
    }
    bool operator<(const box &rhs) const
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < dim.size(); i++)
        {
            if(dim[i] >= rhs.dim[i])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    void print()
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < dim.size(); i++)
        {
            cout<<dim[i]<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
};

int main( )
{
    int n,k;

    while(scanf("%d %d", &k, &n) == 2){
        vector<box> arr;
        vector<box> newarr;
        for(int i = 0; i < k ; i++)
        {
            vector<int> temp;
            for(int j = 0; j < n ; j++)
            {
                int a;
                cin>>a;
                temp.push_back(a);
                std::sort(temp.begin(), temp.end());
            }
            arr.push_back(box(temp,i+1));
            newarr.push_back(box(temp,i+1));
        }

        std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
        cout<<"Increasing Order"<<endl;
        for(int i  =0 ; i < k ; i++)
        {
            arr[i].print();
        }
        std::sort(newarr.rbegin(), newarr.rend());
        cout<<"Decreasing Order"<<endl;
        for(int i  =0 ; i < k ; i++)
        {
            newarr[i].print();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Input :

```
27 2
39 26
63 17
64 46
75 13
26 25
21 45
15 22
41 41
98 92
27 81
37 65
39 25
53 50
72 55
12 42
66 65
10 96
90 90
93 77
24 70
64 49
87 79
33 99
59 11
49 43
43 31
76 85
```

My Output:

```
Increasing Order
12  42  
24  70  
25  39  
11  59  
15  22  
25  26  
21  45  
41  41  
31  43  
43  49  
37  65  
46  64  
50  53  
17  63  
26  39  
33  99  
49  64  
90  90  
77  93  
10  96  
65  66  
55  72  
13  75  
27  81  
76  85  
79  87  
92  98  
Decreasing Order
76  85  
33  99  
92  98  
79  87  
77  93  
90  90  
10  96  
65  66  
55  72  
27  81  
37  65  
50  53  
46  64  
49  64  
43  49  
41  41  
31  43  
26  39  
24  70  
17  63  
13  75  
11  59  
25  26  
21  45  
12  42  
25  39  
15  22
```

Comment: It is dangerous to do the loop like for(int i = 0; i < dim.size(); i++) in your comparison, because if rhs.dim.size() < dim.size() you will run into an out-of-bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write

```
bool operator<(const box &rhs) const
{
    return dim < rhs.dim;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use `std::vector::operator<` (it will do lexicographically compare), example:

```
std::vector<int> a = {0,1,2};
std::vector<int> b = {1,2,3};
std::cout << (a < b);
```

outputs 1.

[Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) you can find vector implements also other operators: =,!=,<,<=,>,>=